# Injeção entre jars

Tags: java, cdi

Tenho um projeto Jar, Helper, que possui um gerenciador de processos, onde controla a execução de threads etal. Onde ele recebe uma interface que realiza a execução quando acionado.

Tenho outro projeto Jar, Service, que implementa a interface da Helper, e injeta um factory do próprio projeto Service.

O erro ocorre quando é executado o código

```
processor = statementProcFactory.getProduct(modelMessage.getProcessType());
```

quando executado via Helper. Testei chamar o processMessage do StatementToPRocessDequeueable dentro do Application do Service, mocando o message, e funcionou sem problemas. O erro ocorre somente quando o processMessage é chamado pelo SQSQueueRunnable.

A estrutura do Helper:

```
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── br
│   │   │       └── com
│   │   │           └── aws
│   │   │               └── sqs
│   │   │                   ├── ISQSDequeueable.java
│   │   │                   ├── SQSDequeueableException.java
│   │   │                   ├── SQSQueueManager.java
│   │   │                   └── SQSQueueRunnable.java
│   │   └── resources
│   │       └── META-INF
│   │           └── beans.xml
```

E a estrutura do Service

```
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── br
│   │   │       └── com
│   │   │           └── reconciliation
│   │   │               ├── service
│   │   │               │   ├── Application.java
│   │   │               │   ├── MainService.java
│   │   │               │   └── statement
│   │   │               │       └── processor
│   │   │               │           ├── IStatementProcessor.java
│   │   │               │           ├── processors
│   │   │               │           │   ├── BanriProcessor.java
│   │   │               │           │   ├── CieloProcessor.java
│   │   │               │           │   ├── RedeCreditProcessor.java
│   │   │               │           │   └── RedeDebitProcessor.java
│   │   │               │           ├── StatementProcessorFactory.java
│   │   │               │           ├── StatementProcessorType.java
│   │   │               │           └── StatementProcessorTypeLiteral.java
│   │   │               └── sqsdequeueable
│   │   │                   ├── StatementToProcessDequeueable.java
│   │   │                   └── StatementToProcessModel.java
│   │   └── resources
│   │       ├── aws.properties
│   │       └── META-INF
│   │           └── beans.xml
```

Main do Service:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new EchoTask(), 0, 1000);

    Weld weld = new Weld();
    WeldContainer container = weld.initialize();
    Application application = container.instance().select(Application.class).get();
    application.run();
    weld.shutdown();
}
```

Casse Application:

```
@Singleton
public class Application {

    @Inject
    private SQSQueueManager queueManager;

    @Inject
    private Provider<StatementToProcessDequeueable> statementProcDequeueProvider;


    public void run() {

        queueManager.addSQSDequeueable(statementProcDequeueProvider.get());
    }
}
```

Método addSQSDequeueable do SQSQueueManager:

```
public void addSQSDequeueable(ISQSDequeueable dequeueable) {

    SQSQueueRunnable runnable = runnableProvider.get();

    runnable.setDequeueable(dequeueable);

    Thread th = new Thread(runnable);

    dictionaryDequeueables.put(dequeueable, runnable);

    dequeueable.startRunning();

    th.start();
}
```

Método run do SQSRunnable:

```
public void run() {
    ReceiveMessageRequest request = new ReceiveMessageRequest(
            dequeueable.getQueue());

    do {

        List<Message> messages = sqsAmazon.receiveMessage(request)
                .getMessages();

        for (Message message : messages) {
            processed = true;

            Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                private Message message;

                public void run() {
                    try {
                        dequeueable.processMessage(message);
                    } catch (SQSDequeueableException e) {
                        // TODO Mover mensagem para fila de erros
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    sqsAmazon.deleteMessage(new DeleteMessageRequest(
                            dequeueable.getQueue(), message
                                    .getReceiptHandle()));
                }

                public Runnable setMessage(Message message) {
                    this.message = message;
                    return this;
                }

            }.setMessage(message));

            th.run();
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(this.getSleepThread());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (isRunning == false)
            dequeueable.stopRunning();

    } while (isRunning);
}
```

Método processMessage do StatementToProcessDequeueable que implementa a interface ISQSDequeueable

```
public void processMessage(Message message) throws SQSDequeueableException {

    logger.debug("Processando mensagem");

    StatementToProcessModel modelMessage = this.generateModel(message.getBody());

    if (modelMessage != null) {
        processor = statementProcFactory.getProduct(modelMessage.getProcessType());

        logger.debug("Processor gerado: " + processor);

        if (processor != null) {

            Statement statement = new Statement();

            Retail retail = repoRetail.getRetailByID(modelMessage.getRetailId());

            List<OperationCard> operations = processor.process(
                    statement.getInputStream(), retail);

            for (OperationCard operation : operations) {

            }

        } else {
            throw new SQSDequeueableException(String.format(
                    "O tipo de processador %s está inválido", processor));
        }
    } else {
        logger.debug("Atributos inválidos da mensagem");

        throw new SQSDequeueableException(
                "Mensagem não possuí todos atributos necessários");
    }
}
```

Classe StatementProcessorFactory

```
@Singleton
public class StatementProcessorFactory {

@Inject
@Any
private Instance<IStatementProcessor> products;

public IStatementProcessor getProduct(String type) {
    StatementProcessorTypeLiteral literal = new StatementProcessorTypeLiteral(type);
    Instance<IStatementProcessor> typeProducts = products.select(literal);
    return typeProducts.get();
}
}
```

Classe StatementProcessorTypeLiteral

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class StatementProcessorTypeLiteral extends
    AnnotationLiteral<StatementProcessorType> implements StatementProcessorType {

private String type;

public StatementProcessorTypeLiteral(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String value() {
    return type;
}
}
```

Interface StatementProcessorType

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface StatementProcessorType {
    public String value();
}
```

Classe que implementa o IStatmentProcessor e tem o qualifier do StatementProcessorType

```
@StatementProcessorType("Banri")
@Stateless
public class BanriProcessor implements IStatementProcessor {
    public List<OperationCard> process(InputStream statementFile, Retail retail) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

Erro:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: WELD-001308: Unable to resolve any beans for Types: [interface br.com.agilebox.gestorfiscal.reconciliation.service.statement.processor.IStatementProcessor]; Bindings: [QualifierInstance{annotationClass=interface br.com.agilebox.gestorfiscal.reconciliation.service.statement.processor.StatementProcessorType, values={[BackedAnnotatedMethod] public abstract br.com.agilebox.gestorfiscal.reconciliation.service.statement.processor.StatementProcessorType.value()=Banri}, hashCode=-1507802905}, QualifierInstance{annotationClass=interface javax.enterprise.inject.Any, values={}, hashCode=-2093968819}]
at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getBean(BeanManagerImpl.java:854)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.InstanceImpl.get(InstanceImpl.java:75)
at br.com.agilebox.gestorfiscal.reconciliation.service.statement.processor.StatementProcessorFactory.getProduct(StatementProcessorFactory.java:19)
at br.com.agilebox.gestorfiscal.reconciliation.sqsdequeueable.StatementToProcessDequeueable.processMessage(StatementToProcessDequeueable.java:31)
at br.com.agilebox.gestorfisccal.aws.sqs.SQSQueueRunnable.run(SQSQueueRunnable.java:64)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

Cada Jar que possui *beans* CDI a serem injetados devem ter um arquivo `beans.xml` na pasta `META-INF`, conforme a [documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbnz.html).

Pode ser um arquivo vazio mesmo. Tente colocar ele nos dois Jars.

Comment: Ambos os projetos tem o beans.xml

Comment: @user11813 Desculpe, sem informações detalhadas da configuração do projeto não é possível ajudar objetivamente.

Comment: adicionai mais informações que possam ajudar a entender o problema

Comment: Mais um comentário, percebi agora que se eu executar ele funciona. Se eu debugar não. Tem alguma explicação??

Comment: @giovanibarili Sem ideias, *sorry*... :(

Comment: Coloquei um codigo exemplo no github https://github.com/giovanibarili/InjectBetweenJars

Comment: Testei no Eclipse de todas as formas possíveis e realmente ocorrem erros variados e aleatórios de injeção. Coloquei o mesmo código da classe `Main` na classe `AppTest` (JUnit) e testei usando `mvn test` e funciona 100% das vezes. Continua não funcionando se rodar o JUnit pelo Eclipse. Enfim, o problema está relacionado ao classloader do Eclipse. *No debug for you, sorry...*

Comment: @giovanibarili Esqueci de marcar você. Veja meu comentário acima ^^^. Por isso eu prefiro mais o Spring!